# How to pass parameter to an api post method?

Tags: symfony, guzzle

I am using guzzle to call my api, and in my url contain one dynamic id
http://myapiurl.com/products/{productId}/phone

```
$client = new Client([
   'base_url' => [
       'http://myapiurl.com/product/{productId}/phone',
       ['productId' => $productId]
     ]
]);

$repsonse = $client->post(
    '/',
     [
         json' => [
             'title' => $title,
             'description' => $description,
          ],
     ]
 );
```

But it generate only http://myapiurl.com (baseurl only)
I can't pass my productId to the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it generate only http://myapiurl.com (baseurl only)

That's because you passed '/' to `post()` method. try :

```
$client = new Client([
    'base_url' => [
        'http://myapiurl.com'
    ]
]);

$repsonse = $client->post(
    '/product/' + $productId + '/phone',
    [
        'json' => [
            'title' => $title,
            'description' => $description,
        ],
    ]
 );
```

Comment: Well, if like that I would be work, but I do not need to forge myself the url like this. Does guzzle provide something that can pass url?

Comment: @vibol I'm not sure that guzzle has that kind of feature.